# Connect an android application to sql server in real device

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services

I wrote an application in android which will sync with SQL-server database that is sitting on my Local Server.
i used web service to connect my apllication to my database and it works perfect in local. Now i want to test it in real device "Samsung" but it gives nothing !
Any suggestion please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you say Local Server, do you mean the database is on your development machine and NOT the phone? You are not using SQLLite for storing data? Usual practice is to use SQLLite (or any other data storing techniques like SharedPreferences or Files) in android but all the data is stored Locally on the device. If you need server side storage, then you need to provide an interface (for e.g. web service) that the phone can talk.

Comment: Thank you for your answer . yes when im talking about local server i mean it's installed on my development machine to test if traitement works .. now i'll use the society server that i work for "distant server" .. i'll appreciate if you explain more .. Thanks

Comment: I would start testing these things. Make sure your web service talks to your remote database. Use the virtual device to talk to the web service and the remote database before testing on the actual device. If this works fine, then your application should work fine from the phone provided you have all the necessary permission and the network itself is enabled. Last thing is, try debugging with your IDE and the phone. That should really help you pin point the exact issue.